# Calculate # of Years Alive in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to finish a quick "demonstration of learning" program by morning for Mothers Day.  I've created a textbox for my mom to enter my birthday and a label to display the number of years, months, days, and seconds I've been alive when she clicks a button.

The following is the part of my code where I am stuck:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime  sonsBirthday = DateTime.Parse(txtSonsBirthday.Text).Date;

    DateTime now =  DateTime.Now;

    TimeSpan timeSpan = now - sonsBirthday;
    timeSpan = Convert.TimeSpan(lblTimeAlive); // blue squiggly under TimeSpan here
```

As I commented in the code, I get a blue squiggly under `TimeSpan` in the last line; but I don't understand why.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm just a student: so I've got the concept but am not used to datetime formats and need a little help.

Comment: Now that's an inventive Mother's Day gift!

Comment: Does the code not build?  Does a runtime exception occur?  Is any information regarding the issue displayed when you hover your mouse pointer over the blue squiggly?

Comment: I think you may have the last line logically backwards.  Don't you want to assign a text representation of `timeSpan = now - sonsBirthday` to `lblTimeAlive.Text`?

Comment: This is correct, I want to parse it the label and I get the following exception:  Error 1 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'TimeSpan'

Comment: Did you mean to do this: `lblTimeAlive.Text = timeSpan.ToString();`? This displays the total time alive in the label.

Comment: Second of all I learned Console. Not Win Forms.  I just had previous experience with WinForms

Comment: I want to show the exact time i've been alive thats all I need.  Then a picture of me is going to pop up with other things for her to enter that will end in a heart warming message.

Comment: Yeah, it is bad enough that Java in CS curricula to the exclusion of more foundational languages has made understanding pointers and explicit memory management "black arts"; God help us if WinForms is in the mix too. :}

Comment: @KenWhite:  The message you suggest is a feature for Sprint 2; this is also a demonstration of progressive elaboration and agile development he has learned. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime  sonsBirthday = DateTime.Parse(txtSonsBirthday.Text).Date;

    DateTime now =  DateTime.Now;

    TimeSpan timeSpan = now - sonsBirthday;
    //timeSpan = Convert.TimeSpan(lblTimeAlive); // old
    lblTimeAlive.Text = timeSpan.ToString(); // new
```

Then fine tune the string formatting for `timeSpan`.

Comment: Thank you! That other guy was pestering me about me doing homework (SWEAR IT IS NOT!)  Im just trying to create a program for my mom for Mothers Day!  Thanks for your help.  I can do everything else I wanted to do now.

Comment: @JeffOrris:  No problemo.  Like I always say, it's your loss if it is for your homework.  The idea is not to learn details that make sense in the particular language/API/framework you are working with as a student as much as to learn how to think critically and how to learn - to thrive through certain change that will replace the details with new ones.  I will take your word, though. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately the "Last Step" is impossible. A year is not a fixed period of time, it also depends on which calendar you use.